# How to get the date value in the table in specific format?

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, date, datetime

I have one problem in my tool. I am using one MySQL table called calendar. From this table I am fetching some date values. The format of date in calendar table is yyyy-mm-dd. But in my system having dd-mmm-yy. In my c# application I fetched the date from the Calendar and If I displayed the date in c# application means date format(2012-10-05) changed to system format(05-oct-12). But I need to display in yyyy-mm-dd format. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Visit <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display DateTime in specific format, you can specify the format in `.ToString()` method like:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; //your DateTime variable
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-mm-ddd"));
```

You may see the article: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you I got Output what i expected